# AJAX return parameters from TCPDF script

Tags: ajax, tcpdf

I write a simply script php, using TCPDF class, to generate a file pdf.
After, in jquery it return the file in base64 and I view in a modal.

This is the ajax code..

```
$.ajax({
    url: path,
    type: 'post',
    data: { myjson: myjson },
    mimeType: 'text/plain; charset=x-user-defined',
    success : function(data) {
        // printPreviewBase64() is a function decodes 'data' and preview pdf in a modal
        printPreviewBase64( data );
    }
});
```

This is the php file..

```
<php
// code to generate pdf
$pdf->Output( $file_name, 'I' );
```

How I can return also other parameters in SUCCESS?
For example I want to return: pdf path, date, author, etc..

Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the pdf date, path, the author in an array then json_encode the array, print it and exit.

Then in your success method in jquery access them with 
data.path,data.date,data.author

Hope this solves your problem

Comment: I just try it, but the problem is "mimeType: 'text/plain; charset=x-user-defined'". So, ajax not return json data..

Comment: Can you post the server side code that ought to return the json.

Comment: Thx Alani, the problem is that ajax return "parsererror" (200) if use code generated by `$pdf->Output( $file_name, 'I' );`, in json_encode() in server-side script.
I've solved that using `$pdf_code = base64_encode( $pdf->Output( $file_name, 'S' ) );`. By this way I can return the variable as base64! After I decode it in js.. and it's all right! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I've solved!!

FIRST. change ajax request with "dataType: 'JSON'":

```
$.ajax({
    url: path,
    type: 'post',
    data: { myjson: myjson },
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function( data ) {
        // data.pdf_code → verrà poi codificato in base64..

        console.log( data.pdf_path );

        //console.log( data.pdf_code );
        printPreviewBase64( data.pdf_code );

    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        console.log(xhr.status);
        console.log(thrownError);
    }
});
```

In the php code I have to change the TCPDF output in..:

```
$pdf_code = base64_encode( $pdf->Output( $file_name, 'S' ) );
```

..and then I return all data in an array JSON.